# Is it possible to mock the session when using Laravel Dusk?

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

My site has a unique setup where the user logins in via OAuth (Socialite) and during login we populate their session with data from this 3rd party.  It's an essential component of our application.  So using Dusk offers limited value unless I create a user on this 3rd party and actually login, unless I can mock/seed the session.  I've been doing some googling and looking through Dusk itself and it's not immediately transparent if this is possible.  **Is mocking/seeding the user's session data possible?**

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how Dusk handles logins by registering special routes in `DuskServiceProvider` and calling them in `InteractsWithAuthentication`.

I image you can use a solution like that for your situation.